# Codeigniter - email library error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to send an email from a codeigniter application, but it gives me this errors:

> Disregard the time error

[image]

Config.php:

```
<?php 
$config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'XXXXX',
                'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXX',
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
                'wordwrap'  =>true
            );
```

Controller: EmailSender.php

```
class EmailSender extends CI_Controller { 

    function index(){       
        //$this->load->library('emailsendermd');  
        //$this->emailsendermd->sendEmail();            
        $this->load->library('email');
   }
 }
```

Comment: its cz of not using `date_default_timezone_set()` and Not Email Error

Comment: Just a tip your name your class wrong only first letter upper case Emailsender same goes for filename explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution from Abudlla Nilam
"its cz of not using date_default_timezone_set() and Not Email Error – Abdulla Nilam Aug 17 '17 a"